# LinkedIn API : How to get public url for a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, plugins, linkedin-api

I am currently developing a Rails web application that requires a user to login through LinkedIn. After that I want to embed the `Member Profile` plugin in his/her profile page.

For that to happen I need to have the public URL, without it the plugin will not work. I already have full profile permission `r_fullprofile` on LinkedIn login. But still I am not able to find the API to extract public url.

Is there a way to get that URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify `public-profile-url` as a default field:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :linkedin, "consumer_key", "consumer_secret", :scope => 'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_network', :fields => ["id", "email-address", "first-name", "last-name", "headline", "industry", "picture-url", "public-profile-url", "location", "connections"]
end
```

and then using the [pengwynn LinkedIn](https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin) gem you can access the URL like so:

```
client = LinkedIn::Client.new
client.authorize_from_access("access_token", "access_token_secret")
client.profile(:fields => ["public-profile-url"])
```

Comment: @mccannf How do you get the access token and token secret, when using [omniauth linkedin](https://github.com/decioferreira/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2)?